# Parsing google weather XML using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [it's a google weather api?how to parse such kind of data using NSXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306214/its-a-google-weather-apihow-to-parse-such-kind-of-data-using-nsxml)

I am trying to make a weather app. I am able to get to google weather api that returns the following XML output (sorry for the bad formatting)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xml_api_reply version="1"><weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" ><forecast_information><city data="Detroit, MI"/><postal_code data="Detroit"/><latitude_e6 data=""/><longitude_e6 data=""/><forecast_date data="2012-02-09"/><current_date_time data="2012-02-09 21:53:00 +0000"/><unit_system data="US"/></forecast_information><current_conditions><condition data="Clear"/><temp_f data="37"/><temp_c data="3"/><humidity data="Humidity: 48%"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/><wind_condition data="Wind: SW at 15 mph"/></current_conditions><forecast_conditions><day_of_week data="Thu"/><low data="25"/><high data="40"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/><condition data="Clear"/></forecast_conditions><forecast_conditions><day_of_week data="Fri"/><low data="13"/><high data="38"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/snow.gif"/><condition data="Snow Showers"/></forecast_conditions><forecast_conditions><day_of_week data="Sat"/><low data="18"/><high data="23"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/><condition data="Mostly Sunny"/></forecast_conditions><forecast_conditions><day_of_week data="Sun"/><low data="20"/><high data="27"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/><condition data="Mostly Sunny"/></forecast_conditions></weather></xml_api_reply>
```

I am able to get current temp what I am unable to get are the temp values for the rest of the days of the week from the XML. I read apple docs and googled this quite a bit but I am not sure how I can parse this string using apples NSXMLParser api. I don't want to deal with other external parsers or include them in my project as my needs are very simple. Following is the code that I have implemented so far

```
- (IBAction)GetCurrentWeather
{

    NSString * location =  @"Detroit";
    NSString * address = @"http://www.google.co.uk/ig/api?weather=";
    NSString * request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",address,location];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
    NSError *error;    
    NSString *XML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"XML: %@", XML);

    // Extract current temperature the 'dirty' way
    //NSString *tempInC = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"temp_c data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempInF = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"temp_f data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *city = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"city data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSString *condition = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"condition data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *humidity = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"humidity data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *wind = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"wind_condition data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dayOfWeek = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"day_of_week data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];

    //NSLog(@"It's dayOfWeek %@", dayOfWeek);
    //NSLog(@"It's tempInC %@ degrees", tempInC);
    //NSLog(@"It's tempInF %@ degrees", tempInF);
    //NSLog(@"It's city %@", city);
    //NSLog(@"It's condition %@", condition);

    NSString *tempStrToDisp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Temp: %@F", tempInF];

//THIS ALL WORKS!!!
        textLable1.text = city;
        textLable2.text = tempStrToDisp;
        textLable3.text = humidity;
        textLable4.text = wind;

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    NSLog(@"XML Parser 1 ...");
    NSLog(@"elementName ... %@", elementName);




//HOW TO GET rest of the week high/low temp VALUES HERE?
 }

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{

    NSLog(@"XML Parser 2 ...");

    //HOW TO GET VALUES HERE?
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    NSLog(@"XML Parser 3 ...");
    //HOW TO GET VALUES HERE?
}
```

Comment: this has been discussed multiple times before - please search, or at least read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306214/its-a-google-weather-apihow-to-parse-such-kind-of-data-using-nsxml), which has a complete code sample in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else in future is interested in parsing this XML string, well here it is. Please rate my answer if it worked for you

```
-(IBAction) GetLocalWeather
{

  NSString *location = @"Detroit";
 NSString *address = @"http://www.google.co.uk/ig/api?weather=";
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",address,location];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
    NSError *error;    
    NSString *XML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"XML: %@", XML);

    // Extract current temperature the 'dirty' way
    NSString *tempInC = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"temp_c data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempInF = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"temp_f data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *city = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"city data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *condition = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"condition data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *humidity = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"humidity data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *wind = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"wind_condition data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];

arryDataMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //TEST
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    int arrySizInt = [arryDataMutable count];
    //NSLog(@"[arryDataMutable count]: %d", arrySizInt);



    /* Weather Conditions 
     Clear 
     Cloudy 
     Fog
     Haze 
     Light Rain
     Mostly Cloudy 
     Overcast 
     Partly Cloudy
     Rain 
     Rain Showers 
     Showers
     Thunderstorm 
     Chance of Showers 
     Chance of Snow 
     Chance of Storm 
     Mostly Sunny
     Partly Sunny 
     Scattered Showers 
     Sunny
     */

    //We will only get 4 day forecast including current day

    //initialize counter
    int counter = 0;

    //skip first entry, its always current day condition
    for (int i=1; i<arrySizInt; i++)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Array: %@", [arryDataMutable objectAtIndex:i]);

        NSString *dayStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[arryDataMutable objectAtIndex:i]];

        //all week-days
        if ([dayStr isEqualToString:@"Mon"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Tue"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Wed"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Thu"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Fri"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Sat"] ||
            [dayStr isEqualToString:@"Sun"] )
        {

            //NSLog(@"counter: %d", counter);

            //get the next 3 values from the array
            //Its always going to be a pair of 4 values
            NSString *lowStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[arryDataMutable objectAtIndex:(i+1)]];
            NSString *highStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[arryDataMutable objectAtIndex:(i+2)]];
            NSString *conditionStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[arryDataMutable objectAtIndex:(i+3)]];

            NSString *tempStrToDisp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ H:%@ L:%@", dayStr, highStr, lowStr];


            //cell-1
            if (counter == 0)
            {

                textLable1.text = tempStrToDisp;

            }

            //cell-2
            if (counter == 1)
            {

                textLable2.text = tempStrToDisp;
            }

            //cell-3
            if (counter == 2)
            {

                textLable3.text = tempStrToDisp;
            }

            //cell-4
            if (counter == 3)
            {

                textLable4.text = tempStrToDisp;
            }

            //increment
            //This will only get incremented 4 times
            counter = counter + 1;
        }


    }//End-for-loop
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    //NSLog(@"XML Parser 1 ... elementName ... %@", elementName);


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"day_of_week"]) 
    { 
        NSString *tempStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]; 
        //NSLog(@"day-of-week: %@", tempStr);

        [arryDataMutable addObject:tempStr];

    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"low"]) 
    { 
        NSString *tempStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]; 
        [arryDataMutable addObject:tempStr];

    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"high"]) 
    { 
        NSString *tempStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]; 
        [arryDataMutable addObject:tempStr];

    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"]) 
    { 
        NSString *tempStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]; 
        [arryDataMutable addObject:tempStr];
    }



}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{

    //NSLog(@"XML Parser 2 ...");
    //NSLog(@"string ... %@", string);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    //NSLog(@"XML Parser 3 ...");
    //NSLog(@"elementName: %@", elementName);
    //NSLog(@"namespaceURI: %@", namespaceURI);
    //NSLog(@"qName: %@", qName);
}
```